# Drawing a circle using mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a circle by clicking and dragging the mouse pointer. The way you would do in PowerPoint or something. The center of the circle is showing up in weird places and I can't explain it.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h8t3hfa2/2/

This is how I get the start and end position;

```
$('#c').mousedown(function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  circle = new Circle();
  circle.start['x'] = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  circle.start['y'] = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;

});

$('#c').mouseup(function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  circle.end['x'] = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  circle.end['y'] = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  circle.draw(canvas[0]);

});
```

When I console log the midpoint it looks correct but the circle shows up somewhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: Check these previous Stackoverflow Q&A: Drawing a circle [outward from the starting drag point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727125/paint-app-in-canvas/28736415#28736415) **and** Drawing a circle [between the starting & ending drag points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727125/paint-app-in-canvas/28736415#28736415):**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because you're scaling your canvas using CSS. Remember, canvas dimensions are different from canvas CSS (style) dimensions.

A quick fix is to equalize them:

```
canvas.get(0).width = canvas.width();
canvas.get(0).height = canvas.height();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h8t3hfa2/3/

```js
var Circle = function() {
  this.start = [];
  this.end = [];
}
Circle.prototype.draw = function(canvas) {
  var me = this;

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var mid = me.getcenter();
    var rad = me.getradius();
    console.log(mid, rad);
    ctx.beginPath();
    console.log(mid['x'], mid['y']);
    ctx.arc(mid['x'], mid['y'], rad, 0, 360);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

};

Circle.prototype.getcenter = function() {
  var me = this;
  //Check the start and end are set
  var centerX = (me.start['x'] + me.end['x']) / 2;
  var centerY = (me.start['y'] + me.end['y']) / 2;

  return {
    'x': centerX,
    'y': centerY
  };
};

Circle.prototype.getradius = function() {
  var me = this;
  var distX = Math.abs(me.start['x'] - me.end['x']);
  var distY = Math.abs(me.start['y'] - me.end['y']);

  return distX / 2;
};

var circle;
var canvas = $('#c');

// added only these two lines
canvas.get(0).width = canvas.width();
canvas.get(0).height = canvas.height();

$('#c').mousedown(function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  circle = new Circle();
  circle.start['x'] = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  circle.start['y'] = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;

});

$('#c').mouseup(function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  circle.end['x'] = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  circle.end['y'] = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  circle.draw(canvas[0]);

});
```

```css
canvas {background-color: white;height: 100%;width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

You should probably also add an onresize event handler to reset the canvas dimensions when the window size changes because you're using a fluid layout. Be careful, though, modifying either of the canvas dimensions (even to the original size) will cause the canvas to clear.

Comment: Aha, that also explains why my circles were distorted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yup, the jagged edges were a dead giveaway that some CSS distortion is going on. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Removing `height: 100%; width: 100%;` from styles <s>fixes</s> avoids the problem.

Off-topic, but I suggest editing `getradius` to use the min (or max) of `distX` and `distY` (instead of hardcoding `distX`) like the applications you mentioned.

```
Circle.prototype.getradius = function() {
  var me = this;
  var distX = Math.abs(me.start['x'] - me.end['x'])/2;
  var distY = Math.abs(me.start['y'] - me.end['y'])/2;

  return Math.min(distX, distY);
};
```

Comment: 100% height and width are there for a reason, so this doesn't fix the problem, but rather avoids it.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry about that. I was just trying to help by pointing out what the cause of the problem is. I updated my answer to say that it "avoids" the problem. I hope this is okay. :/

Comment: No worries, of course it's okay, I just wanted you to improve your answer, because this one modifies the layout of the webpage, which is not something OP wants (I believe). The problem is that the canvas width and height are different from the canvas CSS width and height. :)